# Get browser download count in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my extension, I want to open a webpage once the number of active downloads is under 10.

How do I get the current number of active downloads?

Comment: You can search for downloads where state is "in_progress": https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-search

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for updates using [chrome.downloads.onChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged) and check the quantity of active downloads using [chrome.downloads.search](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-search). You'll need to iterate through each download object and check the `state` property for `in_progress`. It should look something like this:

```
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(changeInfo) {
  chrome.downloads.search({ limit: 0 }, function(items) {
    var activeDownloads = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (item.state == 'in_progress') activeDownloads.push(item.id);
    }
    if (activeDownloads.length < 10) {
      var url = 'http://www.google.com/';
      chrome.tabs.create({ active: true, url: url });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why add the tabs permission?

Comment: It's needed in order to create or update the tab to go to the webpage. In my example, I created a new tab (albeit I should've added a url property) but you could also just update the tab's URL to go to the webpage.

Comment: No, it isn't needed. "The majority of the chrome.tabs API can be used without declaring any permission. However, the "tabs" permission is required in order to populate the url, title, and favIconUrl properties of Tab. "